# Underscore.js - without and difference methods trouble

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

I am trying to use the _.without and _.difference methods in the underscore.js library with no luck.

Here is some code.

```
var someIds = _.pluck(parsedID1, 'id');
var otherIds = _.pluck(parsedID2, 'id);
```

Here is where the trouble starts, I want to remove all of the otherIds out of the someId's list. So I have two options according to the website, either I can use _.difference || _.without. I use them like so...

```
var newArray = _.without(_.toArray(someIds), _.toArray(otherIds));
```

I have also tried to do this with _.difference as well, but I cant seem to get the methods to do anything other than return a copy of the first argument into the function. I have also tried passing the arguments into the functions without using the _.toArray() but the same thing happens.Has anyone ever encountered this error before?

EDIT:

I have tried the way as proposed below. I will give some more code in hopes of fixing this.

The arrays that I am passing in as arguments are in the following format.

```
var array = ['100004191488120', '100004191488321'];
```

When I pass into the _.difference I do as follows:

```
var newArray = _.difference(someIds, otherIds);
```

If someIds length is 657 and otherIds is 57 I should be getting a result of 600 Id's. Instead I get a result of whatever the length of the first argument is, being 657.

EDIT 2: Solved

I figured out what the problem was, after all that frustration the problem lied with the second argument to difference I was passing in.

I was doing a db query and getting back a list that looked like the following.

```
[{ _id: 514721152222111116666777, facebook: { id: '123456789' } },
 { _id: 514721152222111116666778, facebook: { id: '12345678' } },]
```

After I received those results I wanted to get the facebook id so I did the following,

```
var array = _.pluck(users, 'facebook.id');
```

Thats were the problem was, that pluck was sending me back a list of undefined. Instead I had to do 2 plucks before instead of one, like the following.

```
var temp = _.pluck(users, 'facebook'); 
var arrayId = _.pluck(temp, 'id');
```

Thanks @ZenMaster for dropping the knowledge on the difference between _.without && _.difference. Your answer was correct, was pretty brain-dead after a binder and didn't see the obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You don't need an `_.toArray` on the first argument of the `without` function
2. The second (and more) arguments to the `without` is not an array - it's a "list" of values.

The proper call would be:

`var newArray = _.without(['1', '2', '3'], '1', '3');`

which would result in:

`['2']`

In your case, you'd have to use `_.difference` as can be seen on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GdKvv/1/) here.

Here is the code:

```
var parsedID1 = [{id: '1', name: 'name1'}, {id: '2', name: 'name2'}];
var parsedID2 = [{id: '1', name: 'name1'}, {id: '3', name: 'name3'}];

var someIds = _.pluck(parsedID1, 'id');
var otherIds = _.pluck(parsedID2, 'id');

console.log(someIds, otherIds);

var newArray = _.difference(someIds, otherIds);

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Doesn't work, I just tried this again and does the same thing. If I have 2 arrays of the same ID's and same length so the difference should be 0, Instead I get the difference as the size of the first argument.

Comment: The only reason I went to the without method was in hopes of finding another way to easily find the difference between two arrays @ZenMaster

Comment: @Popasquat Of course it works. See the JSFiddle link in the post. If you run two arrays with the same IDs - you get an empty array as a result. EDIT: aha... I see that you've found the issue. Great. Glad to be of help.